# Two articles with same title reading from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

Users can add articles to my websites, and when someone clicks on an article they get a link like this:

```
www.example.com/article/cars
```

"Cars" is the title of the article.

Then I am reading the content of the article from the database with a query:

```
SELECT * FROM Article WHERE Title = 'Cars'
```

But another user can also add an article with the title "Cars". Then it goes wrong... Because the second article about "Cars" will also get the link: `www.example.com/article/cars` and then the query will return 2 articles, while I only want to show one article-data on that page.

So I need to solve this on a way like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Article WHERE Title = 'Cars' AND Id = '1';
```

And for the other one:

```
SELECT * FROM Article WHERE Title = 'Cars' AND Id = '2';
```

But I don't want to have a link like this, to read an article with Title and ID (I want it hidden, and not in URL):

```
www.example.com/article/cars/1
www.example.com/article/cars/2
```

Do you guys know any method how to solve this? Users are allowed to add articles with the same name, but when someone clicks on the link, the content which is read from the databas must be for the right article, without showing the article-id in the URL.

Comment: `...then the query will return 2 articles, while I only want to show one article-data on that page` A non-unique value is not a good choice for the link when you want the link to return one and only one item.

Comment: Do you allow anonymous access to your website, or is the user always signed in, and the article should always be for the signed in user?

Comment: How is the database supposed to know which article the user is requesting if the link is the exact same? Magic? There has to be some differentiation.

Answer (score 0):

do you have a user_article table?  you can allow only unique article names for each user

```
SELECT * FROM Article WHERE Title = 'Cars' AND UserId = '123456789';
```

i'd assume you will know who's article it is when they click on the link

Answer (score 0):

If someone goes to /article/cars you'll just have to show them a list of all of the articles with the title "cars" and make them pick the one they want.

You could always force users to create articles with unique names by adding a UNIQUE CONSTRAINT or NON-CLUSTERED INDEX to the table's Title field.

Answer (score 0):

> Do you guys know any method how to solve this?

Yeah, there are a couple that come to mind. First, include the ID in the URL. I know, you already said you didn't want something like that, but consider a URL like this maybe:

```
www.example.com/article/cars-1
www.example.com/article/cars-2
```

You could work with that. But you'd have to do some **real fancy** work with routing.

The second that comes to mind, and is likely the answer, store the permalink in the database. This will allow you to create the permalink when the article is created the thus tack on some kind of counter, **or a novel idea**, let the user know they need to specify a custom permalink because it's already being used.

Now, instead of pulling the title of the article to build the URL, you pull the actual permalink.

**NOTE:** something that I think is worth noting. Stack Overflow actually houses the ID in the URL for the **exact** reason. The readable URL is built for Google. For example, the link to this post **and** my answer is:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17731295/two-articles-with-same-title-reading-from-database/17731397#17731397
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a page to disambiguate the results. If you type a url like www.url.com/article/car, search in database for articles with "car" title and present both results with unique URLs.